# How do I prevent grails' default main.css being linked on a specific page

Tags: grails

I have a simple web-app that I'm throwing together.

By & large, the default grails `main.css` is fine for all the scaffolded pages.

However, I want to supress this and use different, in-line css for the landing page.

How do I configure grails not to link `main.css` on a specific page?

The html is extremely simple, and contains no grails specific markup:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="layout" content="main" />
<title>My landing page</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">

body
{
background-color: #fff;
}
img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <img alt="Welcome!"
        src="${resource(dir:'images',file:'Landing.png') }">
</body>
</html>
```

Also -- is `main.css` linked purely out of convention, or is there some configuration lurking somewhere I haven't spotted?  (I've done a search but couldn't find it anywhere).

Can someone please reference where in the docs it talks about these conventions?

Comment: Isn't it (=main.css) defined in your main.gsp? The main.gsp is one piece in this puzzle, but how not to import main.css is not something I've done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`main.css` is included in your landing page because you have specified that your landing page is based on the main layout

```
<meta name="layout" content="main" />
```

this layout is defined by `grails-app/views/layouts/main.gsp` and includes the `main.css`, most likely with a tag like this in the `<head>` of the page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'main.css')}" type="text/css">
```

If you remove:

```
<meta name="layout" content="main" />
```

your landing page will no longer be based on the main layout, so it will not include anything defined therein (e.g. `main.css`).

However, rather than removing the layout completely just to prevent `main.css` from being included, it may be simpler to just override the CSS rules that you want to cusomise on the layout page by including custom rules in a `<style>` block in the `<head>` of the landing page

```
<style type="text/css">

  body {
  /* styles in here override styles from main.css */
  }

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the resources plugin in grails 2.0.x. You can define Modules comprising of specific javascript and CSS files which will be compressed, optimized for the web. In the page of your choice, you can include the module you want. In your case, you could add a case like this in your main.gsp

```
<g:if test="${controllerName == "landing"}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'custom.css')}"/>
</g:if>
<g:else>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'main.css')}"/>
</g:else>
```